# Parse and Swift Relations, is this correct?

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, relationships

I have been trying to understand Parse relationships and I'm still not sure if I'm getting them right, please bear with me.

I have an app that downloads data from different countries, as of now, it simply downloads the names and puts them on a tableview, when you click on a cell it takes you to a detailview that shows a scrollview with 3 different images from the country selected, the problem with this is that it is hard to scale it to add more images.

In Parse, I have three columns (image1,image2,image3) and on my app I simply run a Query that adds them into an array, then my scrollview goes through them when you swipe. What I need to to is to be able to add any number of images I want without adding more columns in parse and I thought I could do it like this:

Create an array in Parse, I name it "ImageSet", this image set belongs to a country, so in the "Country" class I have the name of the country, then the ImageSet array.

[image]

Then I create a class named "Images",this class will have two columns, "Name" and "Image". In my app I will assign the "Country" array to all of the images in the "Images" class that has the same name.

[image]

Lets say I add a new Image with the name "Albania" to the images class, In my app I run a query that gets the images, then if they have the same name as the country name, they will get added to the array of the "Country" class. Is this even possible? or am I getting everything wrong here?

Comment: please post the code that you have tried, a picture of parse

Comment: I will post a picture in a second

Comment: and the code you have tried plus the problem you are encountered

Comment: Have you read my question? I added the problem I encountered, I am asking if my approach is even worth trying to code it.

Comment: if i understand you are trying to download data from each specific country with their respective data  or images to display into a tableview

Comment: I want to display them in a detailview, I already managed to do that. What I am trying is to make it more scalable so I don't have to add another pffile column every time I want to increase the images for a specific country.

Comment: so you should create an array of images in parse

Comment: I'm confused about why you opened this question. "Is this even possible?" Yes. "Am I getting everything wrong here?" No. Why do you think you're getting something wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if it is the right approach or if this is something that is normally done, basically that. I didn't want to start coding something that was not going to work.

Comment: The array of references limits you to around 100 images, but is fine. The same name check part confuses me, if you're adding an image you should already know which country it's being added to.

Comment: I know which country it is being added to but my app didn't so I used the name as an identifier, that is how I ended up solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an array.  Simply do this,

have a table "Countries" which has a column "name" being a country name

have a table "CountryImages" which has two columns. One is a pointer to a Country, and the other is a PFImage.

Note that it's difficult to know precisely what you are trying to achieve, but, in the first instance **you should master the simple basic technique I explain above**.

Note that this will only take a matter of thirty seconds to try, so try it and see how you go from there.

Comment: I ended up solving it in a similar way, but instead of using a pointer I simply used a relational query, I did not use a Parse array, instead I just query the images that have the same name as the "Country" object recieved. Basically I just needed to use the name as an identifier, run a query, check if it belongs to the country and add it to a PFFile array in my app.

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for the "tick".  I don't totally follow you, but (IMO) it sounds like essentially you've done the right thing. It's well worth noting that the **array system** on Parse is **something of a bad idea, perhaps a very bad idea**.  They added it to make it "easy" for people who are brand-new to databases.  In general terms, I usually just tell people "simply **do not use** the array system". Hope it helps in some way.